# Why were all comments removed from 4532159

Tags: discussion, comment

All comments made prior to about half an hour ago were removed from [Upper bound for $S(m)=1+\frac{2^{m-1}}{2}+\frac{3^{m-1}}{2^2}+\frac{4^{m-1}}{2^3}+\dots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4532159).

Why is this?

The tone and utility of some of the later comments were maybe not great, but several of the earlier comments I think contributed to the question (such as identifying another expression for the sum in question, linking another question that gives details on how to evaluate the sum, etc.).

Comment: Comments are ephemeral by design.  If something said in comments is worth keeping, incorporate it into a question or answer.  In this case, there were a significant number of flags, and trying to weed out the useful and productive comments from the acrimonious and unproductive comments seemed futile.

Comment: @Xander A moments glance can usually determine if there are useful comments. If so and you don't have the time to weed out the problematic comments then please move them all to chat instead of deleting them all. That is far more constructive.